# ASP.NET MVC 5 Support Lifecycle / End of Life

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting a new project in MVC 5 and I need to give my team an estimate of how much longer Microsoft will be supporting MVC 5. I looked on the [ASP.NET Support Lifecycle Policies](https://www.asp.net/support), which say "the support policy will be to support the current version and the previous version." Then it lists only 5.x, which I assume means they are including .NET Core 1.x as the current version. Does that mean once .NET Core 2.0 is released, they will be dropping off support for MVC 5? According to the [.NET Core Roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md), .NET Core 2.0 is expected for Q3 2017. If they give the "12 month notification" at that point, that would mean support for MVC 5 would end Q3 2018.

That gives it only about 6 months more than "mainstream" MVC 4 support, which is tied to [Visual Studio 2012 Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Visual%20Studio%202012) and ends 1/9/2018. Extended support doesn't end until 1/10/2023. If MVC 5 were tied to Visual Studio 2015, mainstream support would end in 2020 and extend support in 2025.

Does anyone know where I can find more definitive information about MVC 5 support end dates specifically? I know ASP.NET Core MVC works with the full .NET framework, and I've put a lot of effort into learning .NET Core. But in this case, I really would be able to get a release out much faster with MVC 5.

**Update:** I've read a lot of articles like [the one mentioned in the comments](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mvc-5-aspnet-core-now-jani-hyyti%C3%A4inen) and people in the local community generally have suggested using .NET Core for any new projects. However, when I ask people in person if they are *currently* using .NET Core, I have never heard anybody say they are using it in production. I know that there are people out there using it in production and it is possible to use it with the full .NET framework, but it's still missing a lot of tools, features, 3rd party libraries, and documentation that MVC 5 has. I'll admit that if I were better at C# and .NET, I would be probably be able to deal with these problems. The article suggests the 12 month notification for MVC 5 support could come at any time. If that's really the case, I'm not sure I will be able to sell my team on C#/.NET at all.

Comment: An extensive analysis on this subject can be found here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mvc-5-aspnet-core-now-jani-hyyti%C3%A4inen

Comment: mvc 5 is latest stable version

Comment: I do not think there are any definitive end dates declared for MVC5. Even speculation by comparing it to MVC4 is dubious, since MVC5 -> Core is quite different from MVC4 -> MVC5. Support may last longer (or it may not).

Comment: It turns out that predictions about the death of `Web Forms` are greatly exaggerated :) And it's been...a decade or so? Pick the tech stack you and your team are most comfortable with, all the way to _production_  instead of doing crystal balls on matters that you won't have any control over. Hth.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll still have to do some more digging to find something definitive to tell the admins. For those that would vote close this question as "off topic," let me know if there's some way I can edit the question to be better. I searched for "lifecycle support" and found similar questions regarding Angular and Java versions, so I don't think this is really out of place.

Comment: Shaun, what did you end up doing and how is it working out for you? My team is currently thinking about making the switch to Asp.net core for new apps (Asp.net MVC4).

Comment: @eaglei22 Sorry, I wasn't able to find anything definitive. Looking at the support page now ( https://www.asp.net/support ), MVC 4 has a retirement date of July 2019. Still nothing specifically for MVC 5. We ended up using a completely different language. 2017 was not a good time to try jumping into ASP.NET.